# Selecting All rows in datagridview and export it to crystalreport

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datarow

My sample code here is that it only gets 1 row. but i want all rows to be printed. help please. i dont have a database. i add rows programmatically.

If DataGridView1.RowCount > 1 Then

```
        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1

            crparamDV.Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
            crparamFDs = objrpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
            crparamFD = crparamFDs.Item("QTY")
            crParamV = crparamFD.CurrentValues
            crParamV.Clear()
            crParamV.Add(crparamDV)
            crparamFD.ApplyCurrentValues(crParamV)
            Salesrpt.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objrpt
            Salesrpt.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
```

Comment: Are you trying to set parameters and pull only specific rows from the datagrid or you wanting to display everything?  To display all, it's as simple as `objrpt.SetDataSource(DataGridView1.Datasource)`

Comment: i want to display all whats in the datagrid.
i tried your code but it has an error says. "the report has no tables"

Comment: Ah, the report is dynamic as well!  What happens when you comment this out `'crParamV.Clear()` ?  My theory is it is clearing your results on each pass of this loop.